# In Excel VBA, is there a way to extract a range of values from an array where the range of values to be extracted is dynamic?

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I am trying to perform a sum calculation using a set of rolling values in an array in excel VBA where the "lookback" might differ based on an input. For a simple example, this is what I hope to achieve if the lookback is 3.

[Excel Output Example][1]

This is the code that I am testing out:

```
Sub testArr(Lookback As Long)
    
Dim MyArr As Variant, OutputArr As Variant
Dim RowsToExtract As String
Dim i As Long, k As Long, n As Long
Dim SumNum As Double

MyArr = Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(Range(Range("A2"), Range("A2").End(xlDown))))
n = Application.CountA(MyArr)

ReDim OutputArr(1 To n)

For i = Lookback To n
    For k = i - Lookback + 1 To i
        RowsToExtract = RowsToExtract & k & ","
    Next k
    RowsToExtract = Left(RowsToExtract, Len(RowsToExtract) - 1)
    OutputArr(i) = Application.Sum(Application.Index(MyArr, Array(RowsToExtract), 0))
Next i

Range(Range("B2"), Range("B2").Offset(n - 1)) = OutputArr

End Sub
```

However I get the error Run-Time error '13': Type mismatch.

I could do this if I use the range/offset method like:

```
Sub testRange(Lookback As Long)

Dim InputRg As Range
Dim i As Long, n As Long
    
Set InputRg = Range("A2")
n = Application.CountA(Range(InputRg, InputRg.End(xlDown)))

For i = Lookback To n - 1
    Range("B2").Offset(i - 1) = Application.Sum(Range(InputRg.Offset(i - 1), InputRg.Offset(i - Lookback)))
Next i

End Sub
```

As the list gets enormously large and several other calculations are needed (not only sum), it takes quite long if I use range/offset method. Hence I am trying to see if using the arrays will speed things up but I am unable to slice(?) a dynamic set of values from the array. Is there a way to go about doing this?

Comment: You may want to edit your post to include the sample data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (processes 1 048 576 values in 2,4 sec.):

```
Option Explicit

Sub RollingSum()
    Const Lookback = 7
    Dim cnt, cntB, i, ssum
    Dim a(), b()
    
    With ActiveSheet
        a = Intersect(.Columns(1), .UsedRange)
        ReDim b(1 To UBound(a) - Lookback + 1, 1 To 1)
        cntB = 1
        For i = LBound(a) To UBound(a) - Lookback + 1
            cnt = 1
            ssum = 0
            Do
                If cnt > Lookback Then
                    b(cntB, 1) = ssum
                    cntB = cntB + 1
                    Exit Do
                End If
                ssum = ssum + a(i + cnt - 1, 1)
                cnt = cnt + 1
            Loop
        Next
        
        ' output
        .Range("B1:B" & UBound(b)) = b
    End With
End Sub
```

[image]

### Edit2 (universal)

```
Sub RollingRangeProcessing()
    t = Timer
    Const Lookback = 7
    Dim cnt, cntB, i
    Dim a(), b(), c()
    
    With ActiveSheet
        a = Intersect(.Columns(1), .UsedRange)
        ReDim b(1 To UBound(a) - Lookback + 1, 1 To 1)
        
        cntB = 1
        For i = LBound(a) To UBound(a) - Lookback + 1
            cnt = 1
            ReDim c(1 To Lookback)  'reset array c()
            Do
                If cnt > Lookback Then  '
                    With WorksheetFunction
                        'here use the appropriate array processing function
                        b(cntB, 1) = .Sum(c)
                        'b(cntB, 1) = .Average(c)
                        'b(cntB, 1) = .Median(c)
                    End With
                    cntB = cntB + 1
                    Exit Do
                End If
                c(cnt) = a(i + cnt - 1, 1)
                cnt = cnt + 1
            Loop
        Next
        
        ' output
        .Range("B1:B" & UBound(b)) = b
    End With
    Debug.Print "Total time to process " & UBound(a) & _
                " values = " & Round(Timer - t, 1) & " sec."
End Sub
```

**Output:**

```
Total time to process 1048576 values = 6,5 sec.
```

[image]